# How to insert new data from a local table to a remote table but not copy the exists data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm making a small program that copy data from databaseA to databaseB.
Because table in databaseA are exactly the same with tables in databaseB
So I can use query below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME@dbLinkB SELECT * FROM DatabaseA
```

---

But I have 2 issue:

1. I got tables with more than 50 millions rows. Is there any method to insert data with better performance?
2. When I want to insert my data from databaseA to my databaseB but not insert the records which have already exists. Any suggestion, please

Thanks

Comment: Food for thought - how do you identify what has already been inserted?

Comment: I think could use the primary key, but other tables have different primary key, I haven't found any good way